# iOS Autolayout has a delay before updating

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autolayout

I am trying to use autolayout in my app. I have a button that changes the size and position of a UIView when it is pressed.

I use the code below but the layout isn't updated straight away. There's a delay of about 20 seconds before the UI is updated. If I put the code inside viewDidLoad however it appears as soon as the view does.

Is there a method that forces the layout to be updated?

```
NSArray *constraintArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[_response]-335-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:viewDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:constraintArray];
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: There's nothing in your posted code that should cause a 20 second delay. The problem must be somewhere else. Are you doing anything else  at the same time that is a long running process?

Comment: I am displaying a keyboard on screen but nothing else I can see. Other code that I put in the same place always runs instantly and sometimes the code above runs instantly as well but usually there is a long delay.

Comment: It's hard to tell what might be happening, especially if it doesn't always happen. It probably won't change anything, but I don't think you need the setNeedsUpdateConstraints line.

Comment: Are you running this code on a queue or thread that is not the main queue/thread?

Comment: No everything is running on the main thread. To fix the delay I ended up adding a 1 X 1 pixel view onto the screen. I'm not entirely sure why this fixes the problem, it seems as though the constraints don't think they need to be updated and the extra view triggers something.